# How to zip two arrays into one array which every array contains another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to "zip" values from two arrays into 1 array. E.g. I got an array with titles: `['Cukier biały premium', 'second item']` and the second array with quantity of the titles  `[1, 999]` i.e. `Cukier biały premium` quantity is `1` and should be in array and so on.. and I'd like to get an array with values of these two arrays from index[0] and so on. But the problem is that inside this two arrays are more arrays inside:
I got

```js
 const productTitles = order.map((item) => item.productTitle);
  const productQuantity = order.map((item) => item.quantity);
  console.log('product titles', productTitles); // output:  [Array(2), Array(3)] 
  console.log('product quantities', productQuantity); // output: [Array(2), Array(3)]

  const merged = productTitles.map((title, i) => [title, productQuantity[i]]);
```

[image]

How to Zip the `merged` array to got data like: `["Cukier biały premium", 1]` and `["second item", 999]` in one array and so this is order 1 () that I can `.map` over and display it in orders page? the second array (order 2) should contain an array of `["Cukier biały premium", 1], [Cukier czarny, 1], [Cukier amerykanski, 1]`

Tried like this but got an array of `[undefined, undefined]`

```js
const merged2 = productTitles.map((title, i) => {
    productQuantity.map((quantity, index) => {
      [title[i], quantity[index]];
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right basic idea. Issue you had is you were mixing up the indexes. And you were not returning anything in the map calls.

```js
const productTitles = [
  ['a', 'aa'],
  ['b', 'bb'],
];

const productQuantity = [
  [1, 11],
  [2, 22],
];

const merged2 = productTitles.map((row, rowIndex) =>
  row.map((value, columnIndex) => [value, productQuantity[rowIndex][columnIndex]]));

console.log(merged2);


// Use flatMap if you do not want a nested array

const mergedFlat = productTitles.flatMap((row, rowIndex) =>
  row.map((value, columnIndex) => [value, productQuantity[rowIndex][columnIndex]]));

console.log(mergedFlat);
```

Comment: How can I display it separately. Because now I got an array of two arrays which in each array I got arrays which contains title of the product and quantity in each array. It sounds complicated :D

Comment: The "mergedFlat" flatMap one is not what you want?

Comment: with `mergedFlat` I got one array `merged2` which contains 5 arrays inside (but 2 arrays are the order 1 and the rest three arrays are order 2). If I `.map` over this array `merged2` I will show all 5 arrays which contains 2 orders inside

Answer (score 1):

Short solution but not performant for big list since we call `productQuantity.flat()` on every iteration:

```
productTitles.flat().map((p, i) => [p, productQuantity.flat()[i]])
```